# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws, noclassdeffounderror

The rest services are deployed in the jBOSS server. When I try to access a particular web service, I am getting the following exception.

```
10:34:32,579 SEVERE [ContainerResponse] The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at $Proxy628.getFolderType(Unknown Source)
    at com.dsths.awd.wsdl.client.workflow.WorkFlowClient.validateFolderType(WorkFlowClient.java:139)
    at com.dsths.pm.services.WorkFlowService.validateFolderExist(WorkFlowService.java:390)
    at com.dsths.pm.services.ConfigurationGetService.getConfiguration(ConfigurationGetService.java:78)
    at com.dsths.pm.comlayer.SteppPMConfigurationServlet.getConfiguration(SteppPMConfigurationServlet.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
```

I have placed "jaxws-rt.jar" file in the JBOSS lib folder, but still getting the same exception. Anybody has any ideas on this?

Comment: What version of Java? What version of JBossAS?

Comment: I am using java 1.6 and JBOSS 5

Comment: Strangely, I am able to access another web service without any issue, the problem comes with only one specific web service.

Comment: So get rid of `jaxws-rt.jar` from everywhere because it is a part of Java 6. Additionally, there are significant differences between JBossAS 5.0 and 5.1, so you need to be far more specific

Comment: I am using Jboss-5.1.0

Comment: @Ashok.N - Have you solved this issue? Can you please post the solution here?

Comment: @Ashok.N - Can you please post the solution?